# Process validated information of 7 employees according to example console interaction

Tags: java, validation, class, oop, enums

*Big breath* lol
So, in my college programming class for Java, we need to create a program
that process first, last, regular-hours, sick-hours, and the hourly wage for
an assumed 7 employees. I'm almost positive my professor is trying to stress
more object-oriented programming and the use of enumerated data types in this
project. Luckily, our merciful master offered an example of the console interaction shown here:

```
Employee #1:
Enter the employee’s first name: XXXXXXX
Enter the employee’s last name: XXXXXXX
Enter the number of hours worked: XX.XX
Enter the number of vacation/sick hours: XX.XX
Enter the hourly wage: XX.XX
Employee #2:
Enter the employee’s first name: XXXXXXX
Enter the employee’s last name:
Invalid! The employee’s name must be at least on character long.
Enter the employee’s last name: XXXXXXX
Enter the number of hours worked: -10.00
Invalid! The hours worked must be between 0 and 80 hours.
Enter the number of hours worked: XX.XX
Enter the number of vacation/sick hours: XX.XX
Enter the hourly wage: XX.XX
…
Name Hours V/S Gross Pay Tax Take-Home
XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX XX.XX XX.XX XXXX.XX XXXX.XX XXXX.XX
XXXXXXX, XXXXXXX XX.XX XX.XX XXXX.XX XXXX.XX XXXX.XX
…
Total XXXX.XX XXXX.XX XXXXXX.XX XXXXXX.XX XXXXXX.XX
```

I have each of the validating methods finished, and we are only required to
use 2 classes, Driver and Employee with whatever static methods we think
we should use showing care for efficiency. My classes are currently as follows:
Driver Class

```
package project2;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * This program calculates an employee's weekly
 * take-home wages based on the number of hours
 * and the hourly wage.
 * @author ***********
 *
 */
public class Driver 
{

    // Employee's First Name
    static String firstName;

    //Employee's Last Name
    static String lastName;

    //The amount of regular hours worked
    static int regHours;

    //The amount of vacation/sick hours
    static int vsHours;

    //The hourly wage of pay
    static float wage;

    //The deducted tax
    static String taxDeduction;

    //Total pay to take home
    static String takeHome;

    //Number of employees (assumed)
    static final int iters = 7;

    /**
     * Manages interaction with user
     * throughout program.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner ( System.in );


    }

    /**
     * Checks to see if there is an
     * alphabetical character in
     * an employee's name.
     */
    public static boolean validName ( String name )
    {
        boolean hasOneAlpha = name.matches(".[a-zA-Z]+.*");
        return hasOneAlpha;
    }

    /**
     * Validates the regular hours of an
     * employee to not be greater than 80
     * hours.
     */
    public static boolean validHours ( int hours )
    {
        if ( hours > 80 )
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    /**
     * Validates the sick or vacation hours
     * of an employee to not be greater than
     * 40 hours.
     */
    public static boolean validSick ( int vsHours )
    {
        if ( vsHours > 40 )
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    /**
     * Validates the wage of an employee
     * to ensure the wage is less than $100/hr
     * and not less than or equal to 0.
     */
    public static boolean validWage ( float wage )
    {
        if ( wage > 100.00 || wage <= 0.0 )
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
}
```

And my Employee Class:

```
package project2;

public class Employee 
{

    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int regHours;
    int vsHours;
    float wage;
    static float earnings;
    float tax;


    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, int regHours,
            int vsHours, float wage)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.regHours = regHours;
        this.vsHours = vsHours;
        this.wage = wage;
    }

    /**
     * Establishes tax rate based on
     * earnings.
     * @return 
     */
    public float taxDeduction()
    {
        earnings = totalPay();
        if ( earnings > 900 )
            tax = (float) 0.15;
        else if ( earnings >= 300 )
            tax = (float) 0.13;
        else
            tax = (float) 0.11;
        return ( earnings * tax );
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the net pay after
     * a tax deduction.
     */
    public float netPay()
    {
        earnings = totalPay();
        float taxDeduction = taxDeduction();

        return ( earnings - taxDeduction );
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the total amount paid
     * to the employee.
     */
    public float totalPay()
    {
        int totalHours = ( regHours + vsHours );
        if (( vsHours <= 20 ) && ( totalHours > 40 ))
            if ( totalHours - 40 >= vsHours )
                earnings = (float) (( 40 * wage) + (( totalHours - 40 - vsHours ) * 1.5 * wage) + (( vsHours ) * 1.25 * wage ));
            else
                earnings = (float) (( 40 * wage ) + (( totalHours - 40 ) * 1.25 * wage ));
        else if ( regHours > 40 )
            earnings = (float) ( totalHours * wage + ( regHours - 40 ) * .5 * wage );
        else
            earnings = totalHours * wage;

        return earnings;
    }

}
```

I guess what im really asking, is how do i iterate through employees, process
the information for each of them respectively, and output each Employee object
with a row specifically for total. Criticize away, still learning. I'll have more time off of work to study more often but, unfortunately, that's after my due date :(

I sincerely thank anyone who was able to read this all and any help is greatly appreciated! Sharing knowledge is after all the purpose of life. <3CS

Comment: Normally, you'd use a `List` to store the information, but since you already know that there are only 7 employees, you can get away with an array.  I'd start with a `for-loop`, incrementing from `0-6` and capture the details you need, maybe even using some kind of factory method.  Each employee would then be stored within the appropriate element in the array.  Once you have the information, you could use an enhanced `for-loop` to iterate over the array and process it as required...

Comment: First, thank you for the incredibly hasty response! :D

Comment: Also i knew i would need for loops just not quite sure where to start with it

Comment: Create a new class which acts as the primary input driver...

Answer (score 0):

The below sudo can work with some modifications In your main method

```
for(int i=0;i<iters;i++)
   fname <- read
   while(validName(fname) != true)
     fname <- read
   lname <- read
   while(validName(lname) != true)   
      lname <- read
   regHours <- read
   while(validHours(regHours) != true)
      regHours <- read
  // like that write for the remaining properties
  Employee emp = new Employee(firstName,lastName,regHours,vsHours,wage)
  System.out.println("Name Hours V/S Gross Pay Tax Take-Home"); 
 // get what ever you want according to your logic like emp.taxDeduction()
  System.out.prinltln("Total ")
  System.out.println(emp.totalPay())
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch! However my only question pertaining to your example is the " <- read "  portions

Comment: @DamianinJava since it is psudo code i have mentioned like that, so here `<- read` means read the data from user example `scannerObject.nextInt()` or `scannerObject.nextLong()` or `scannerObject.next()` according to your requirement